# JS works perfectly locally, not at all once uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JS that is working perfectly on my local machine, as soon as I upload it to my web server it stops functioning. The site is www.turnbulldesigns.co.uk if you want to take a look.

I have uploaded the entire folder structure from my local machine so it's not wrong/missing files. What could stop the following JS from working once uploaded?

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(".orange").click(function () {
        $("#colors").attr("href", "colors/orange.css");
    });
    $(".blue").click(function () {
        $("#colors").attr("href", "colors/blue.css");
    });
    $(".green").click(function () {
        $("#colors").attr("href", "colors/green.css");
    });
    $(".red").click(function () {
        $("#colors").attr("href", "colors/red.css");
    });
    $(".violet").click(function () {
        $("#colors").attr("href", "colors/violet.css");
    });
    $(".pink").click(function () {
        $("#colors").attr("href", "colors/pink.css");
    });
    $(".yellow").click(function () {
        $("#colors").attr("href", "colors/yellow.css");
    });
    $(".tan").click(function () {
        $("#colors").attr("href", "colors/tan.css");
    });
    $(".grey").click(function () {
        $("#colors").attr("href", "colors/grey.css");
    });

    $('.color-switcher li a').click(function (e) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })

})
```

Comment: Define `not working`? What errors do you get?

Comment: can you define "stops functioning"? Do you get errors? If so, what errors? Have you determined that the click is calling the function, and the function is misbehaving, or that the function isn't being called?

Comment: If you give a link to the uploaded stuff, we can inspect it.

Comment: The website is in the original question :-)

Comment: `tweet.js: Twitter Error: "Invalid or expired token", Error Code #89`.

Comment: By not working, it simply doesn't change the style for the page when you click.

Comment: Please see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Such questions are not a good fit for SO.

Comment: How did you find that error?

Comment: you are key has expired or the domain to which key is registered is another

Comment: @ClaudioRedi if you submit that as an answer I will accept, that was the source of the problem thanks!

Comment: *"How did you find that error?"*: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: @ScottHelme Just a small observation: 0.5MB background JPG is **not** a good idea. Try to decrease it's quality or something, this is just too big.

Comment: @Scott Helme: done :)

Comment: @MightyPork you're right, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the link, will take a look now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript error on that page is related to twitter

`Twitter Error: "Invalid or expired token", Error Code #89`

Probably you're using a token that is domain dependent and that's what is causing you troubles.

For future reference: it's very easy to detect these kind of problems using browser developer tools.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) you have will find a tutorial for Chrome tools. No need to download anything as they are part of the browser.

And [here](http://getfirebug.com/) you can download the equivalent Firefox plugin (firebug)